# Fast pull data.frame rows with different value in previous row

Tags: r, dataframe

I am interested in extracting information from a data.frame in which the value of a given entry in the data frame differs from the previous. Here is an example frame:

```
df <- data.frame(name = rep("a",5), val1 = c(1,1,2,2,2), val2 = c(10,11,12,13,14))

> df
  name val1 val2
1    a    1   10
2    a    1   11
3    a    2   12
4    a    2   13
5    a    2   14
```

I am interested in extracting the information in rows 2 and 3, where `val1` changes from 1 to 2. I can do this by iterating over every entry in the data frame, keeping track of the previous `val1` such that when it changes I can pull the two relevant rows, but I'm wondering if there is a faster or more efficient way of doing this for when the data frame is very large. R typically has faster ways of extracting information than iteration, but I'm not sure what to use here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One method is to use `diff` and logical subsetting:

```
keepers <- diff(df$val1)
df[as.logical(c(0, keepers) + c(keepers, 0)),]
  name val1 val2
2    a    1   11
3    a    2   12
```

`diff` captures the change in value. 0s are prepended and appended to capture the first row after the change and the last row before the change and these vectors are added together, resulting in a vector of 1s and 0s. `as.logical` turns this into a logical vector which is used to subset the rows.

Answer (score 2):

With `diff` you can take advantage of the fact that `diff` gives you one value less than the number of rows. With:

```
which(diff(df$val1)==1) + 0:1
# instead of '==1' you can also use '>0' or '!=0': which(diff(df$val1)!=0) + 0:1
```

you get an index of the row before and the row after the change:

```
> which(diff(df$val1)==1) + 0:1
[1] 2 3
```

Therefore:

```
df[which(diff(df$val1)==1) + 0:1, ]
```

results in the desired outcome:

```
  name val1 val2
2    a    1   11
3    a    2   12
```

---

Another nice R-tric is comparing the result of `head` and `tail`:

```
which(head(df$val1,-1) != tail(df$val1,-1)) + 0:1
```

this results in the same index (off course!).

Comment: Would `diff` be faster because it's a single operation?

Comment: @oregano not sure, you'll have to test that

Answer (score 1):

This is essentially same problem as selecting the first and last row of a group. From there you can remove the first and the last row. A simple data table solution would be:

```
library(data.table)
zz=data.table(df)
yy=zz[, .SD[c(1,.N)], by=val1]
yy[2:(nrow(yy)-1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `lag` from `dplyr` to get the index of rows which are not similar as previous one and then also select one row above that by subtracting 1 from that index.

```
library(dplyr)
i1 <- which(df$val1 != lag(df$val1))
df[sort(c(i1, i1-1)),]

#name val1 val2
#2    a    1   11
#3    a    2   12
```

Another example,

```
df <- data.frame(name=rep("a", 7),val1=c(1,1,2,2,2,3, 3), val2=c(10,11,12,13,14, 15, 16))
df
df
#  name val1 val2
#1    a    1   10
#2    a    1   11
#3    a    2   12
#4    a    2   13
#5    a    2   14
#6    a    3   15
#7    a    3   16

i1 <- which(df$val1 != lag(df$val1))
df[sort(c(i1, i1-1)),]

#  name val1 val2
#2    a    1   11
#3    a    2   12
#5    a    2   14
#6    a    3   15
```